# How to extract the img src value of an <img ... /> tag from a string in velocity

Tags: velocity

I am getting an RSS feed that contains img tags and in my backend velocity script, I want to extract the img src.

So, the RSS feed includes at a paragraph with an img tag like this:

```
<p>
<img alt="" src="//path1/path2/path3/imagename.jpg?x=1499453513435" style="margin: 5px; width: 313px; height: 400px; float: left;" />
Some text goes here...
</p>
```

The above is an example of the description element of the RSS feed.

I am trying to extract the img src.

I have tried something like:

```
#set($index1 = $!content.description.indexOf("<[^>]*>"))
#set($index2 = $!content.description.indexOf("/>"))
#set($index2 = $index2 + 2)
#set($imgsrc="$!content.description.substring($index1, $index2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended using to successfully extract the image path (including the image name) of the img src value:

```
#set($index1 = $!content.description.indexOf("src="))
#set($index1 = $index1 + 5)
#set($index2 = $!content.description.indexOf("?x="))
#set($index2 = $index2)
#set($imgsrc=$!content.description.substring($index1, $index2))
```

I first explored

```
#set($index1 = $!content.description.indexOf("src="))
#set($index1 = $index1 + 5)
#set($index2 = $!content.description.indexOf("?x="))
#set($index2 = $index2)
#set($imgsrc=$!content.description.substring($index1, $index2))
```

and it worked, but I changed to the alternative after considering that the image extension may not necessarily be .jpg